# How to connect android with .net webservice

Tags: android, web-services

i m trying a lot but can not call the web service in android i cant understand what is the problem.i m posting my code here=

> java code is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                editText = et.getText().toString();
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();

            } else {
                tv.setText("Please enter name");
            }
        }
    });
}
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        displayText = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(editText,"AuthenticateUser");
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        tv.setText(displayText);
        pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

> web service is :

```
private static String NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL ="http://192.168.5.106/smartwebservice/smartwebservice.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/";
public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;       
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);       
    PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();      
    sayHelloPI.setName("Name");      
    sayHelloPI.setValue(name);       
    Set dataType  sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);         
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();   
        resTxt = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured";
    }
    return resTxt;
}
```

> Logcat is :

Thread-1578(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
08-31 14:24:14.067 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 I/System.out: Thread-1578(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/AuthenticateUser.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@42816af8
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:147)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.piechart2.WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(WebService.java:49)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.piechart2.CheckDNLoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:57)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.piechart2.CheckDNLoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:53)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-31 14:24:14.687 4288-4712/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-31 14:28:28.697 4288-4288/com.example.dell.piechart2 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

I m not able to call web service with android.when i enter name error occurred. What should i do now ?? anyone can me ?

Comment: Did you try to Google out your problem ? As I see lot of solutions out there :)

Comment: i have tried alot...but no solution solved my problm..

Comment: i cant understand what's the problm..

Comment: is there any problem in my code ??? plzzz tell me...i need ur help

Comment: What is displayText ? and you need to send String name in your WebService not the editText, you are sending editText replace it with editText.getText.toString() check if that helps

Comment: same error occored

Comment: i made it from this website - http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/

Comment: [SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@d307dbe]......this is the main error

Comment: Give me time to implement and check it myself

Comment: okk sure...thnk u

Comment: the web service which i want to call is not in my system. I call it through ip address of anothr system. is it a prblm ???

Comment: Try this out seems to work http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100

Comment: i have tried it..and i got an error...-android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fed0eb5b6d0

Comment: according to code of given link i tried but when it directly open this (http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight) then error occured File or Directory not found. May be because of this NetworkOnMainThreadException occured.

Comment: Why are you doing network request on main thread than doing it in background thread ?

Comment: i updated my code.

Comment: i used asyncTask for this..nut still i get error in dobackground method